# How to import external module/library in web2py pythonanywhere

Tags: python, web2py, pythonanywhere

I am a beginner and have been using web2py on the online webapp form in pythonanywhere. I wish to use the googlemaps api however I'm not sure how to install the modules. On my local python I just installed it through terminal, however I am not sure how to do it on pythonanywhere online. Any help would be appreciated :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This help page](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules/) explains how to install things on PythonAnywhere.  Basically, you'll either need to use the `--user` flag with `pip`, or a virtualenv.